# Create audio file with many audio chunks (WAV) using ffmpeg or sox

Tags: linux, bash, audio, ffmpeg, sox

I'm searching on a method that can help me creating an audio file (of known length) composed by mixing some audio chunks at specific time position.

For example: 
I want to create song.wav with duration of 5 minutes, composed by:
- chunk1.wav (time 0:02)
- chunk3.wav (time 0.50)
- chunk2.wav (time 1:20)

I think I can create 5 minutes of silence then mixing the wave files but I don't know how.
I try SOX but no solution found yet
I'd like also FFMPEG based solution

Comment: Adapt the method at https://superuser.com/q/1092291/114058

Comment: Does not seem to work. i tried it and return Illegal instruction. Could be possible for the file format?

Comment: Without a log, can't diagnose. Run command with `-report`

Comment: Find out that the compiled version was the cause of this problem.Illegal instruction is given also if the binary is of the wrong version (in my case armh and I have to use armel version).Now launching this command work like charm. Thanks a lot. I'm searching on it from 4 days. If you answer I give you the vote ;)